# Как продолжить счетчик времени на onStop(),onPause()

Tags: java, android

При выхода из приложения, но не закрывая его как можно продолжить счетчик времени ?

```
private Timer timer;
private int second = 0;
private int minute = 0;
private int hour = 0;
private TimerTask timerTask ;
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   timer = new Timer(false);           
   timerTask = new TimerTask() {             
    public void run() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
              public void run() {                    
              second++;
              if(second == 60){
               minute++;
               second=0;
               }else if(minute==60){
               hour++;
               minute=0;
               }else if(hour==24){
               hour=0;
               }

    }
});
}          
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000,1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо вынести задачу в сервис. Задача, исполняющаяся в сервисе не зависит от жизненного цикла активити.

Comment: спосибо так  и думал :)